# How to configure Oracle wallet to avoid ORA-29273 when request geocoding?

Tags: oracle, google-maps, oracle11g

I got a problem to get geocoding from Google when I used a government licensed Google API key. This project is developed for government, so we should be able to use this API key. And I was told by government agent that as long as I use this API key and they add our company's domain to their list, we should be able to get geocoding without Google free limit. I am using Oracle 11gR2, Apex 4.1. The google does return some result (1600 geocodings) and after a while my program had exception.However, I got the following problem:

```
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1722
ORA-29259: end-of-input reached
ORA-06512: at "SORS.SOR_TEST_SERVICE", line 24
ORA-06512: at "SORS.SOR_TEST_SERVICE", line 187
ORA-06512: at line 6
29273. 00000 - "HTTP request failed"
*Cause: The UTL_HTTP package failed to execute the HTTP request.
*Action: Use get_detailed_sqlerrm to check the detailed error message.
Fix the error and retry the HTTP request.
```

and I searched online and found the following thread on OTN:

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2253491

It looks I need to get Google API certificate and install it on Oracle wallet. I do not any experience about it. Can anyone give me a road map about it? For example, how can I get a Google certificate? Shall I contact with Google, or send request with license API key? or API key is a certificate? an example would be very helpful!

Here is my code

```
   procedure Get_Geocoding(P_s_Address in varchar2, P_s_Geocoding out varchar2, P_n_accuracy out    number, P_b_success out boolean) is

  l_address varchar2(4000);
  l_url varchar2(32000);
  l_response varchar2(3200);
  n_first_comma number;
  n_second_comma number;
  n_level_length number;

 BEGIN
    /* TODO implementation required */

    l_address:=APEX_UTIL.URL_ENCODE(P_s_Address);
    l_address := replace(l_address,' ','+');

    l_url := 'http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q='||l_address||'&'||'output=csv'||'&'||'key=my API key';
    l_response := utl_http.request(l_url, APEX_APPLICATION.G_PROXY_SERVER);



    n_first_comma:=instr(l_response,',',1,1);
    n_second_comma:=instr(l_response,',',1,2);
    n_level_length:=n_second_comma-n_first_comma-1;

    P_n_accuracy:=to_number(substr(l_response,n_first_comma+1, n_level_length));

    l_response:=substr(l_response,instr(l_response,',',1,2)+1);



   P_s_Geocoding:=l_response;
     if (P_s_Geocoding<>'0,0') then
       P_b_success:=true;
     else
      P_b_success:=false;
     end if;

 END;
```

}

Thanks a lot!

Sam

Answer (score 0):

check the db version if your db version is 11.2.0.3 or below, this error can come.
You need to install a patch to upgrade tls based security. The minimum version for this is 11.2.0.4.0. Oracle has provided a patch(19651773) for windows to upgrade the version.